# Extract multiple 5 digit numbers from strings

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract multiple 5 digit numbers from strings which contain text and different length numbers. All 5 digit numbers will be proceeded with "DRxxxxx".

And example of source data:

DR32007 DR32008 DR32009 DR32010 ordered on 11/26/18 with John Boyles.

I have a function which extracts all the numbers:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^\d]", ";"), "[^\d\-\;]", ""),"-", ";"), ";")))
```

And this outputs the following:

```
32007   32008   32009   32010   11  26  18
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to extract just the 5 digit numbers (all proceeded by "DRxxxxx") and not the other numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using regex you can look for digits and using brackets for a minimum number of occurrences like \d{5,} will find 5 occurrences of the digits.  You can also put parentheses around DR(\d{5,}) so it can be a capture group and not include the DR if you don't want that

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions from Google Sheets forum:

From: Spence Farris:

```
=filter(IFERROR(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^\d]", ";"), "[^\d\-\;]", ""),"-", ";"), ";"))),LEN(IFERROR(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^\d]", ";"), "[^\d\-\;]", ""),"-", ";"), ";"))))=5)
```

From: maddy ...

```
=filter(right(split(A1," "),5),regexmatch(split(A1," "),"DR\d{5}"))
```